# SBJson and Facebook iOS SDK error "no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'JSONValue'"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk, sbjson

I get an error saying:

`"no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'JSONValue'"` ??

It happens when I have a data stream (NSDAta) NSDictionary * dict = [data JSONValue];

I have only the SBJson files that came with the facebook SDK. Can someone help me understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "data" should actually be a "`NSString`" object.

Then you can do something like this (assuming the JSON data is in the variable named "data"):

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
if(json_string)
{
    NSDictionary * facebookDict = [json_string JSONValue];
}
```

Also make sure you "`#import "NSString+SBJSON.h"`" at the top of the .m file this code lives in.

Comment: this was a interesting solution... I didnt use it in the end but it is a working solution thanks.